# VB6 Debugger - Command line arguements

Tags: vb6

In the VB6 IDE there is a window were you can specify command line arguements (for debugging).  If you create a .exe with arguements specified, will they be published with the application? I don't believe they will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they will not. This is just for testing your application if it uses command line arguments. It allows you to specify your command line arguments and step through exactly like if the program was called with those command line arguments.

For example, you normally pass parameters by simply calling your EXE and providing the parameters at the same time. So, if you normally call your program like such

```
C:\test.exe /test /inet /copy
```

You would simply set the command-line arguments to

```
/test /inet /copy
```

in the VB6 IDE

Comment: I thought so.  I just wanted to check.  I assume that you append the parameters to the path to pass command line arguments?

Comment: Yes, I know and I will.  Can you answer my question in the above comment?

Comment: Refined my answer to explain it. Does that help?